# Fruityloops not playing certain notes

Tags: software, fl-studio

I'm new to Fruityloops and sound editing software in general and I wanted to learn more about it. I wanted to recreate a song I like and learn from that process.

Sadly I'm already encountering problems I cant seem to fix myself. There are certain notes that Fruityloops just wont play if there's is another pattern playing at the same time.

In the video provided you can see pattern one and two playing, pattern two is mainly just some short bursts of F#4 and note 1 and 6 of pattern one are also F#4. When both both patterns need to play an F#4 at the same time pattern one stays silent. When I remove pattern two it pattern one DOES play those notes. Does anyone know what's causing this?

Here's a picture of my two patterns:

[image]

Here's the video where you can see the problem:

Comment: Maybe it's a monophonic synth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I definitely don't think Unison is going on here, simply because the notes aren't playing at all.

What's happening is that the notes are conflicting with each other. You're playing one note at the same time, same octave, AND at the same instance of both notes. FL doesn't really know how to handle it so my guess is that it plays the last note you put into the piano roll and omits the other.

It's a pretty simple fix, either have two dedicated instances of the virtual instrument for each region or change the octave of one of the regions.

Comment: Yes! Duplicating the instument worked for me. I find it strange though that the software actually sees them as separate now even though it is the exact same instrument and only a copy within the step sequencer. You would think that because it's a different pattern the software would see it as two separate instruments...

Not really the fix I had hoped for (because I like to keep the step sequencer to be tight and tidy) but it works. 

Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: This guy said the same thing i said -_-

Answer (score 1):

Ok

If they are both the same note AND the same synth AND the same patch that means they are going to be played in UNISON. Imagine playing a piano and then playing the same note on a completely identical piano at the same time. It wont double up, it will be the same sound in the wave.

You have to adjust the velocity in piano roll or load another instrument (the FLS strings one) and make one louder than the other. Hope this helps (^_^)y-~

Comment: Well the strange thing is that the note in one pattern is longer then the other in the other pattern, so even if they don't double up I should be hearing the long one. In this case I actually only hear those short bursts. Boosting the velocity didn't help either but thanks for your reply!